# How to externalize version info in AndroidManifest.xml?

Tags: android

As part of our nightly build, we generate a build stamp. This information needs to go into the versionCode and versionName fields. My first thought was to generate a custom resource file, say, build.xml, that has these two values as string resources and then just refer to them within AndroidManifext.xml.

```
 <manifest
    android:versionCode="@string/version_code"
    android:versionName="@string/version_name"
    ...
 </manifest>
```

It appears, however, that these two fields cannot take a resource url.

I am wondering if there is any other way to solve this problem.

I could generate a new AndroidManifest.xml as part of the nightly build. However, that may be a bit excessive for controlling just two fields.

Comment: Specifics/limitations of the build system?  Can you just run arbitrary shell scripts and do this with, e.g., `sed`?

Comment: You can inject this sort of stuff with the new Gradle for Android-based build system fairly easily.